# "I felt you when ..." or "I felt it when ..."

Tags: single-word-requests, poetry

Please have a look at the following poetic line:

"...I felt you when you washed up on an unknown coast..."

Can I say "I felt you..." (to stress exactly my emotional proximity to the other person) or it is not right and only saying "I felt it..." makes sense?

My post is partly inspired by the following article: https://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk/news/liverpool-news/message-love-liverpool-tracey-emin-3473408

where it is written that an artist has signed with the following phrase:

“I felt you and I knew you loved me”.

Comment: (Thank you very much for your downvote...I mean...you can answer my question if it is so simple etc)

Comment: Poete_Maudit, I see you are anxious to get a satisfactory answer. No one says it is simple, but it looks like a proofreading question. You need to include the research you have done. By the way, although I was not the downvoter, I believe they did due to lack of research.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @haha. I have already done some research but I have not found any reliable source (except perhaps for this urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20feel%20you) and this why I wanted to know the opinion of native speakers (if they are actually educated enough to know this)..

Comment: To my knowledge, both of your options are correct, and I would say it depends on what you want to say. Edit your question to include more information. Maybe someone more knowledgeable than me weighs in.

Comment: Yes, I agree to this. I shared it also with a couple of educated friends of mine and they did not notice anything. By the way, even if I edit my question to include more information then I do not think that I will exactly add so much context to it. By definition, poetry is perhaps the least contextual text that you can get owing to its metaphors and analogies. (This is also exactly why poetry will be the last thing which will be grasped by artificial intelligence and natural language processing more specifically.) The only context is that I express my empathy and my love to a woman.

Comment: You need to edit your post if you want an answer. For some reason I shouldn't edit your question, but you need to. Your question hasn't been closed yet, but if you don't edit or put more information it will soon be closed. And please identify a specific source of concern.

Comment: (I am starting to form the impression that you downvoted my at the beginning...you cunning @haha....I am joking)...I edited my post. However, I do not know if it is better now.

Answer (score 2):

I think "I sensed you" would fit better, since it doesn't have the vernacular baggage that "I feel you" has (that "felt" carries with it too).

Comment: Thank you for your response(upvote). This is a pretty good idea especially for avoiding the more vernacular baggage of "feel" as you say. However, the word "sense" derives partly its meaning from the word "senses" which also haa more physical or even pedestrian/vernacular meaning whereas the word "feel" has a stronger emotional baggage which is better for a (sort of) love poem....

Comment: Whether "sense" will have that physical baggage in context might be more of a go-out-and-survey-people type problem. For example, Googling "I sensed her" results for me in mostly discussions not about physical sensation, but about mental and emotional connection.

Comment: Yes, I Googled it too and it is more emotionally/mentally related. I will think about it for some time and I will see. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I rarely see "sense" used to describe physical sensation in common conversation. In fact, more often I see "feel" used for physical sensation instead. So I think the etymology might not have such an impact.

Comment: Hm, interesting thought too. The problem is that, as with humans, words may be considered to be of similar meaning to that of their family even though in a sense they may be entirely different. This was partly my objection. But yes I agree with you in what you are saying.